# Nested NIntegrate with a function in between

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to do an nested NIntegrate in which there's a function in between; for example:

```
f[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2/2] Cos[x^2 z/10], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
NIntegrate[Log[f[z]],{z,0,10}]
```

Unfortunately, when I try to do this, I get the typical error:

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand E^(-(x^2/2)) Cos[(x^2 z)/10] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{[Infinity],0.}}.

I thought adding NumericQ would make this go away, but it didn't work. Any tips on how to work around this? Apologies if this has been asked before; I wasn't sure how to properly word the question.

Comment: Works for me without any error message.  Mathematica 10 on OSX 10.11.5.  Try seeing if typing f[3] gives a numerical answer.

Comment: probably you defined `f` without the `?NumericQ`, then redefined it with `?NumericQ` but didn't `Clear` the original def.  Either do `Clear[f]` or restart the kernel

Comment: I also have such a message, if using it without `?NumericQ` (Mma 11.1, Win7). That's strange I remember to have done such things without such messages in one of the previous versions. Can anybody explain this?